# Iterating over ng-repeat with inline array updates all objects in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

in AngularJs I have two arrays: One with weeks and one with occupancy-numbers.
Now at first I'm iterating over the week-array in a table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in weeks">
<!-- content for every week with occupancy-array -->
</tr>
```

In this table I have implemented a second ng-repeat for the occupancy-array, with the following structure per week:

```
Array[WeekId] = {early: null, late: null, night: null}
```

So for 3 weeks, the object exists 3 times.

The objects should be manipulatable for every week with an input-field.
So my HTML is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in weeks">
    <td ng-repeat="(title, value) in occupancies[week.id]">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="value"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But in this case, I have a problem by reaching the new values, because the array won't be changed in scope.

So then I decided to change my 2nd ng-repeat to this:

```
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="occupancies[week.id].early"/></td>
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="occupancies[week.id].late"/></td>
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="occupancies[week.id].night"/></td>
```

Now, the scope will be changed, but with the problem, that the objects in my occupancy-array are mirrored. That means by changing occupancy-early in week 1 will change occupancy-early in the other weeks too.

I need help!

Comment: Can you provide [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yes, wait. I changed structure for working without $index.

Comment: Here is it: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lmq8ub5/

Comment: I didn't get it runnable, because it's my first JS Fiddle, maybe you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try assign object to occupancies and try again.

```
$scope.occupancies = {};
```

Comment: The same issue. But I thought about deleting the part of setting the occupancy array, because its unnecessary since I don't use the second ng-repeat. Now it works!